# Help understanding the notation used on ar-drone tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, for the tutorial link:[text](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#cameras), under

> Sending Commands to AR-Drone

It shows three highlighted commands which are: `ardrone/takeoff` `ardrone/land` and `ardrone/reset`. These are topics so is the full commands actually: `rostopic /ardrone/takeoff` `rostopic /ardrone/land` and`rostopic /ardrone/reset` ?

Also, to fly the drone after takeoff, would I do something like: `rostopic cmd_vel -linear.x` to move the drone backwards?

I am trying to understand how to read the commands listed, sorry that this is basic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73522/help-understanding-the-notation-used-on-ar-drone-tutorial/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you want to send a message from terminal you should use the command like:

```
rostopic pub /ardrone/land std_msgs/Empty
```

For /cmd_vel you should use the command like:

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-18**:
Brilliant! One thing that I would have not known from the tutorial is std_msgs/ Is this used to say 'I am going to send an empty message' ?

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-08-18**:
Yes, it is.

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-18**:
thank you !

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-19**:
Just to check, for the section https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#cameras am I correct to say the commands to get a stream of the front and bottom cameras are:

$ rostopic pub ardrone/front/image_raw image_transport and 
$ rostopic pub ardrone/bottom/image_raw image_transport

?

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-08-19**:
Hi. Do you want to toggle camera?

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-19**:
hi, nope I would like to display the front facing camera on my computer screen if possible.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-08-20**:
You need to use image_view package. Like this "rosrun image_view image_view image:=/ardrone/image_raw"

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-20**:
Perfect. Thank you Alexandr!